# JQ map objects to array with condition

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have this input data:

```
[
  {
    "attributes": {
      "created": "2021-10-18T12:02:39+00:00",
      "enabled": true,
      "expires": null,
      "notBefore": null
    },
    "contentType": null,
    "id": "https://kjkljk./secrets/-/1",
    "managed": null,
    "name": "pw",
    "tags": {}
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "created": "2021-10-18T12:06:16+00:00",
      "enabled": true,
      "expires": null,
      "notBefore": null
    },
    "contentType": "",
    "id": "https://kjklj./secrets/-/2",
    "managed": null,
    "name": "pw",
    "tags": {}
  }
]
```

I need to use jq to extract the id values into a new array where enabled is set to true.  this is what I have so far:

```
.[] | select(any(.attributes; .enabled== true)) | {id}
```

but it only results in this:

```
{
  "id": "https://kjkljk./secrets/-/1"
}
{
  "id": "https://kjklj./secrets/-/2"
}
```

how can i make these two objects into an array of strings instead?

```
[
  "id": "https://kjkljk./secrets/-/1",
  "id": "https://kjklj./secrets/-/2"
]
```

Comment: `[ "id": "https://kjkljk./secrets/-/1", "id": "https://kjklj./secrets/-/2" ]` isn't valid JSON.  You said "array of strings", so did you mean `[ "https://kjkljk./secrets/-/1", "https://kjklj./secrets/-/2" ]`?

Answer (score 22):

Use `map` instead of `.[]` to retain the array:

```
map(select(any(.attributes; .enabled)) | {id})
```

```json
[
  {"id": "https://kjkljk./secrets/-/1"},
  {"id": "https://kjklj./secrets/-/2"}
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/rdzVB96ze7)

Note that this produces an array of objects `[{…},{…}]`, what I believe is what you asked for although in your desired output you are missing the curly object braces `{` `}`. To make an "array of strigs" instead, use `.id` instead of `{id}` like so

```
map(select(any(.attributes; .enabled)) | .id)
```

```json
[
  "https://kjkljk./secrets/-/1",
  "https://kjklj./secrets/-/2"
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/LlmNqV15FG)

(Also, you can use `.enabled` instead of `.enabled == true`)

Answer (score 9):

Something like:

```sh
$ jq '[.[] | select(.attributes.enabled) | .id]' input.json
[
  "https://kjkljk./secrets/-/1",
  "https://kjklj./secrets/-/2"
]
```

Comment: Can be shortened and made more readable so: `map(select(.attributes.enabled).id)`

Answer (score 2):

Like already written in the answers, comments before, your wished output is not valid json.

So you have to options. I pasted your input file in `SO-70302009.json`

1. Wrap the id line as objects `jq 'map({id: select(any(.attributes; .enabled)) | .id})' "./SO-70302009.json"`
   to get

```json
[
  {
    "id": "https://kjkljk./secrets/-/1"
  },
  {
    "id": "https://kjklj./secrets/-/2"
  }
]
```

2. Make an array of ids `jq '{ ids: map(select(any(.attributes; .enabled)) | .id) }' "./SO-70302009.json"`
   to get

```json
{
  "ids": [
    "https://kjkljk./secrets/-/1",
    "https://kjklj./secrets/-/2"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
map(select(any(.attributes; .enabled == true)) | .id)
```

Explanation: Rather than splitting the array with `.[]`, the `map()` function leaves the array structure intact but operates on the elements. Using `.id` rather than `{id}` avoids creating a dictionary for each selected value.

If I understand right, you could also replace `any(.attributes; .enabled == true)` with just `.attributes.enabled == true`.