# How to extract a field from an array of JSON objects in AWS Athena?

Tags: sql, json, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I have the following JSON data structure in a column in AWS Athena:

```
[
  {
    "event_type": "application_state_transition",
    "data": {
      "event_id": "-3368023833341021830"
    }
  },
  {
    "event_type": "application_state_transition",
    "data": {
      "event_id": "5692882176024811076"
    }
  }
]
```

I would like to somehow extract the values of `event_id` field, e.g. in the form of a list:

```
["-3368023833341021830", "5692882176024811076"]
```

(Though I don't insist on exactly this as long as I can get my event IDs.)

I wanted to use the `JSON_EXTRACT` function and thought it uses the very same syntax as `jq`. In `jq`, I can easily get what I want using the following query syntax:

```
.[].data.event_id
```

However, in AWS Athena this results in an error, as apparently the syntax is not entirely compatible with `jq`. Is there an alternative way to achieve the result I want?

Comment: Use `map` instead of `.[]` to retain the array, as in `map(.data.event_id)` [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/Mlh3S86VD9X); or see [JQ map objects to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70302009/jq-map-objects-to-array)

Comment: As I sad, this is happening within Amazon Athena. I can solve the problem using `jq`, but unfortunately that database environment only supports different syntax for querying JSON. Are you sure what I want is even possible in Athena?

Comment: If you are looking for a `jmespath` solution, you should replace the `jq` tag accordingly.

Comment: I am not sure if Athena supports `jmespath` or not, it seems like it does not. I am looking for a solution I can plug into the `JSON_EXTRACT` function as shown in the [AWS doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/extracting-data-from-JSON.html).

Answer (score 1):

`JSON_EXTRACT` supports quite limited set of json paths. Depending on Athena engine version you can either process column by casting it to array of maps and processing this array via [array functions](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html):

```sql
-- sample data
with dataset(json_col) as (
    values ('[
  {
    "event_type": "application_state_transition",
    "data": {
      "event_id": "-3368023833341021830"
    }
  },
  {
    "event_type": "application_state_transition",
    "data": {
      "event_id": "5692882176024811076"
    }
  }
]')
)

-- query
select transform(
    cast(json_parse(json_col) as array(map(varchar, json))),
    m -> json_extract(m['data'], '$.event_id'))
from dataset;
```

Output:

| _col0 |
| --- |
| ["-3368023833341021830", "5692882176024811076"] |

Or for 3rd Athena engine version you can try using Trino's [`json_query`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/json.html#json-query):

```sql
-- query
select JSON_QUERY(json_col, 'lax $[*].data.event_id' WITH ARRAY WRAPPER)
from dataset;
```

Note that return type of two will differ - in first case you will have `array(json)` and in the second one - just `varchar`.