# Syntax for extracting data from JSON

Tags: jq

I need to extract some info from JSON. My JSON looks like this:

```json
{
  "pipeline1": {
    "description": "Desc 1",
    "last_modified": "2023-11-14T09:27:50.235Z",
    "pipeline_metadata": {
      "version": 1,
      "type": "logstash_pipeline"
    },
    "username": "user1",
    "pipeline": "code",
    "pipeline_settings": {
      "pipeline.batch.delay": 50,
      "pipeline.batch.size": 125,
      "pipeline.workers": 1,
      "queue.checkpoint.writes": 1024,
      "queue.max_bytes": "1gb",
      "queue.type": "memory"
    }
  }
}
```

Expected output:

```json
{
  "pipeline": "pipeline1",
  "description": "Desc 1"
  "last_modified": "2023-11-14T09:27:50.235Z"
  "username": "user1"
  "pipeline": "code"
}
```

Is it possible with `jq`?

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it? Guidance is available at https://jqlang.github.io/jq/. But note your expected output has _two_ properties named `pipeline`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expected output contains a duplicate key `pipeline`, which jq cannot produce by regular means. But if you accept another name for one of them, e.g. renaming the first one to `parent`, you could get your expected output by decomposing the input with `to_entries`, and then assigning all the target values:

```bash
to_entries[]
| {parent: .key} + (.value | {description, last_modified, username, pipeline})
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/6t3NKUn6kUn)

Comment: The pipeline key is wrong in your demo.

Comment: Ah, because it's a duplicate key. Changed its name. Thanks for spotting.

Comment: Ah, duplicate key was a mistake. Really appreciate this!

Comment: I also need to separate each "block" with a ","
Should be possible i think

Comment: Same as with the duplicate keys: Just putting commas between the objects isn't possible (by regular means), as it [wouldn't be JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) anymore. Either take it as-is (as a stream of objects), or turn it into an array (with surrounding brackets **and** commas in between). The latter can be achieved by either enclosing the whole filter with brackets `[to_entries[] | {…} + (…)]`, or by not descending into the items in the first place by [replacing `.[]` with `map`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70302009/70302131#70302131): `to_entries | map({…} + (…))`